openai-java getting 404 with OpenRouter
I can access using baseURL https://api.openai.com/ but I am getting a 404 exception trying to access OpenRouter.   I am using the code below to specify the baseURL using the example in openai-java issue 454. I have tried baseURLs https://openrouter.ai/api/v1/chat/completions/ and https://openrouter.ai/api/v1/.  I have tried three free models, which all say to use that completions baseURL.
Here is the code I am using.  The exception occurs on the final line.
      String userKey = "<my_openrouter_key>";    
      String model = "mistralai/mistral-7b-instruct:free"; // tried two others 
      String baseURL = "https://openrouter.ai/api/v1/chat/completions/"; // tried https://openrouter.ai/api/v1/, https://api.openai.com/ works
      ObjectMapper mapper = OpenAiService.defaultObjectMapper();
      OkHttpClient client = OpenAiService.defaultClient(userKey, Duration.ofSeconds(30))
                .newBuilder()
                .build();
      Retrofit retrofit = null;
        try {
            retrofit = OpenAiService.defaultRetrofit(client, mapper)
                    .newBuilder()
                    .baseUrl(new URL(baseURL))
                    .build();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
      OpenAiApi api = retrofit.create(OpenAiApi.class);
      OpenAiService service = new OpenAiService(api);        
      CompletionRequest completionRequest = CompletionRequest.builder()
                .model(model)
                .prompt("Somebody once told me the world is gonna roll me")
                .echo(true)
                .user("testing")
                .n(3)
                .build();
      service.createCompletion(completionRequest).getChoices().forEach(System.out::println); // HTTP 404

